# How to do Inner Join with multiple rows return JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two tables with one which has multiple rows in reference to the other table.

questions_table:

```
id | value_question
---------
1  | "first question"
2  | "second question"
```

responses_table:

```
id | question_id| value_response | is_true
-------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | SFU            | true
2  | 1          | UBC            | false
3  | 2          | BU             | true
4  | 2          | RI             | false
```

I would know which is the best practice to return each rows from questions_table in JSON from PHP as this:

```
[
  { "value_question": "first question",
    "responses": [
      {"value_response": "SFU", "is_true": "true"},
      {"value_response": "UBC", "is_true": "false"}
    ],
  },
  { "value_question": "first question",
    "responses": [
      {"value_response": "SFU", "is_true": "true"},
      {"value_response": "UBC", "is_true": "false"}
    ],
  },
]
```

I'm trying to do it only in MYSQL but I only reach to sort a string.

```
SELECT 
     value_question,
     CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT('{value_response:',responses.value_response,', is_true:',responses.is_true,'}'),']')'responses' 
FROM questions
INNER JOIN responses ON 
     questions.id = responses.question_id
GROUP BY id_question
```

I don't know what is better between doing this in the PHP or with MYSQL.
If you need more details tell me.

Thanks, I know how to use json_encode, my question is more: which is the best request to have a structure as described.

the php:

```
    include 'connect_db.php';

    $sql= *the request*

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json = json_encode($result);

    echo $json;
```

Comment: The best approach will be to first fetch the result rows from a simpler query then use PHP and `json_encode()` to produce organized structure you are looking to get. Please post the PHP code you are using to query and fetch, so we can know which MySQL API you use (MySQLi vs PDO) and recommend the best approach. You should _not_ attempt to construct the JSON string inside your MySQL query.

Comment: You're trying to do something in SQL for which SQL is not really suited. And trying to concatenate it all together like that is painful and prone to error. Michael's suggestion is best.

Comment: I edited with the PHP. I know concat as a string is not a good way to do something like that, but it's the  solution the more similar to my goal that i find.

Comment: as suggested by Michael Berkowski, best way is PHP's json_encode, but you need output in such format where your required to use multiple result row in single row for example in responses, For particular your requirement, making JSON output using GROUP_CONCAT would work best, you can create a view and use it's output directly

Comment: select qs.value_question, rs.value_response, rs.is_true from questions_table as qs INNER JOIN responses_table as rs
ON qs.id=rs.question_id
;
run this sql which will give you the data from mysql like below
{"value_response": "SFU", "is_true": "true"},
      {"value_response": "UBC", "is_true": "false"}
Then you can process this result set like you want using php.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.
For database connection please replace with your mysql database server values in mysqli_connect function.
I have used mysql query and php mysqli, since I am not much aware of PDO. 
First taking request in a variable, then run a mysql join query. Iterate over mysql fetched result and build up an array. Then finally do json_encode.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('db_host', 'db_username', 'db_password', 'db_name'); // please replace with your mysql server values.

$value_question = 'first question'; // your *the request*

$value_question = $con->real_escape_string($value_question); // escape values

$query =  " SELECT `responses_table`.`value_response` , `responses_table`.`is_true` 
            FROM `questions_table` 
            INNER JOIN `responses_table` 
            ON `questions_table`.`id` = `responses_table`.`question_id` 
            WHERE `questions_table`.`value_question` = '$value_question' "; 

$result = $con->query($query);

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ // build up a responses array
    $responses[] = array( 'value_response' => $row['value_response'] , 
                            'is_true'       => $row['is_true'])  ;
}
$response = array('value_question' => $value_question ,
                    'responses' => $responses );

echo json_encode($response); // your json response
```